# Using Spark Scala in EMR to get S3 Object size (folder, files)

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the folder size for some S3 folders with `scala`  from my command line EMR.

I have JSON data stored as GZ files in S3. I find I can count the number of JSON records within my files:

```
spark.read.json("s3://mybucket/subfolder/subsubfolder/").count
```

But now I need to know how much GB that data accounts for.

I am finding options to get the size for distinct files, but not for a whole folder all up.

Comment: @DenisMakarenko : He wanted to print distinct file sizes rather than folder

Comment: I've closed it too fast. The title is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am finding options to get the size for distinct files, but not for a
>   whole folder all up.

Solution :

---

***Option1:***

Get the s3 access by FileSystem

```
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(ipPath), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```

Note :

> 1)  `new URI` is important other wise it will connect to
>   hadoop file system path instread of s3 file system(object store :-)) path . using new URI you are giving scheme `s3://`
>   here.
>
> 2) `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize` will
>   give display sizes of file system in GB MB etc...

```
      /**
    * recursively print file sizes
    *
    * @param filePath
    * @param fs
    * @return
    */
@throws[FileNotFoundException]
@throws[IOException]
  def getDisplaysizesOfS3Files(filePath: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path, fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem): scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = {
    val fileList = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
    val fileStatus = fs.listStatus(filePath)
    for (fileStat <- fileStatus) {
      println(s"file path Name : ${fileStat.getPath.toString} length is  ${fileStat.getLen}")
      if (fileStat.isDirectory) fileList ++= (getDisplaysizesOfS3Files(fileStat.getPath, fs))
      else if (fileStat.getLen > 0 && !fileStat.getPath.toString.isEmpty) {
        println("fileStat.getPath.toString" + fileStat.getPath.toString)
        fileList += fileStat.getPath.toString
        val size = fileStat.getLen
        val display = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size)
        println(" length zero files \n " + fileStat)
        println("Name    = " + fileStat.getPath().getName());
        println("Size    = " + size);
        println("Display = " + display);
      } else if (fileStat.getLen == 0) {
        println(" length zero files \n " + fileStat)

      }
    }
    fileList
  }
```

based on your requirement, you can modify the code... you can sum up all the distinct files.

***Option 2*** : Simple and crispy using `getContentSummary`

```
implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ObjectSummary").getOrCreate()
  /**
    * getDisplaysizesOfS3Files 
    * @param path
    * @param spark [[org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession]]
    */
  def getDisplaysizesOfS3Files(path: String)( implicit spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession): Unit = {
    val filePath = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path)
    val fileSystem = filePath.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val size = fileSystem.getContentSummary(filePath).getLength
    val display = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size)
    println("path    = " + path);
    println("Size    = " + size);
    println("Display = " + display);
  }
```

*Note : Any option showed above will work for 
local or 
hdfs or 
s3 
as well*