# How to get number of files read from S3 path in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

So, I'm using the most generic S3 read code in Spark, it reads multiple files in my specified directory into a single dataframe:

```
val df=spark.read.option("sep", "\t")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("encoding","UTF-8")
  .schema(sch)
  .csv("s3://my-bucket/my-directory/")
```

What would be the best way (if any) to get the ***number of files*** that were read from this path?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350298/using-spark-scala-in-emr-to-get-s3-object-size-folder-files

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't exactly solve my case. I want the number of files/partitions that are read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to count distinct `input_file_name()` :

```scala
val nbFiles = df.select(input_file_name()).distinct.count
```

Or using Hadoop FileSystem:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val s3Path = new Path("s3://my-bucket/my-directory/")
val contentSummary = s3Path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration).getContentSummary(s3Path)

val nbFiles = contentSummary.getFileCount()
```

Comment: Thanks. As an add-on, what should I do (in Spark) to get the total filesize (in bytes) of all the files read from my directory? In other words, the total size of my dataframe?

Comment: @DebapratimChakraborty check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35008549/1386551) for the size.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my purpose, but I just want to ask - when I read a csv into a dataframe, does spark make any metadata about it? Like say size, number of rows etc?

Comment: Going to advise against getContentSummary as its a woefully single threaded inefficient treewalk. Avoid using against any object store